# Selecting "Use hardware acceleration when available" causes issue where the browser can't launch

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

In the process of making some adjustments in options, I selected "**Use hardware acceleration when available**", on next attempted relaunch I got a message basically saying 'something has caused the program to stop' (had to paraphrase because I didn't make a note of the message). I had to reinstall to get it to open. My questions are "what causes this to happen?", and "is there a known solution, other than having to reinstall?".

Thank You,
Imho

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue why this breaks the browser but you can change hardware acceleration back to disabled in order to to restore the browsers functionality.

In order to do this you have to find the file prefs.js in profile.default and change it according to fix 2 of this link:

http://www.askvg.com/how-to-disable-hardware-acceleration-gpu-rendering-in-mozilla-firefox-4-0-to-fix-font-problem/